# wubi bcdedit error?

Tags: 12.04, windows, wubi

When I try to uninstall Ubuntu (only to reinstall it, of course) from windows, I get an error message about a bcdedit error. What is this and how do I fix it? And yes, I am using wubi.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, but please take extreme care while following this solution:

[image]

Step 1: Try and uninstall Ubuntu via Wubi and note down the part of the error shown in the image above.

Step 2: Download EasyBCD 2.0 (Google), install it and create a boot entry. To do this, launch EasyBCD and goto Add/Remove Entries. Now click the Linux/BSD tab and set the Type to "Wubi" and give it the name "Ubuntu". Finally, click "Add Entry".

[image]

Step 3: Now close EasyBSD and enter "cmd.exe" in the Windows search box on the start menu. Right click cmd.exe and select "Run as Administrator". Now, type "bcdedit.exe" into the Command Prompt window and hit enter.

It will spew a lot of writting into the Command Prompt but we want the end of it (Real-mode Boot Sector). Find the entry named "Ubuntu" and note down the identifier.

[image]

Step 4: Close cmd.exe and now search for "regedit.exe" the same way as we did cmd.exe. Now goto Edit > Find and then search for the bit of text we took note of in the error at the beginning.

If all is well you should get a screen like the one shown below. We are going to edit the "VistaBootDrive" entry. Right click on it and select "Modify". Now delete the text shown in the box and replace it with the identifier you took note of from the Command Prompt earlier and click OK.

Step 5: Now attempt to uninstall Ubuntu via Wubi again and all should be well.

[image]